# Проблема с операцией сложения в функции python

Tags: python, tkinter

> Напишите простой калькулятор, который считывает с пользовательского
>   ввода три строки: первое число, второе число и операцию, после чего
>   применяет операцию к введённым числам ("первое число" "операция"
>   "второе число") и выводит результат на экран.
>
> Поддерживаемые операции: +, -, /, *, mod, pow, div, где
>
> mod - это взятие остатка от деления,
>   pow - возведение в степень,
>   div - целочисленное деление.
>
> Проверьте все исключительные ситуации, выведите сообщение для
>   пользователя.

```
from tkinter import *
import math

window = Tk()
window.title("Hi")
window.geometry('450x250')

num1 = Entry(window)
num1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

num2 = Entry(window)
num2.grid(column = 2, row = 1)

num3 = Entry(window)
num3.grid(column = 3, row = 1)

lbl = Label(window, text = "-")
lbl.grid(column=4, row = 1)

def fun():
    a = int(num1.get())
    b = int(num2.get())
    c = str(num3.get())
    if c == "+":
        x = a + b
        lbl.configure(text=" Сумма = %x ." % x)
        lbl.grid(column=3, row=2)
    else:
        lbl.configure(text="% Error")
        lbl.grid(column=3, row=1)

btn = Button(window, text = "Посчитать", command = fun)
btn.grid(column = 4, row=2 )
window.mainloop()
```

Выполнил первую часть задания и столкнулся с проблемой. При вводе числе больше 7, в ответе выдаются буквы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%x` - это спецификтор для вывода числа в шестнадцатеричном виде  (x - не название вашей переменной, а x из "hexadecimal"). Чтобы вывести как десятичное число, используйте `%d` (для целых чисел) или `%s` (универсальное):

```
lbl.configure(text=" Сумма = %d ." % x)
```

Или используйте `{}` и метод `format`:

```
lbl.configure(text=" Сумма = {} .".format(x))
```

Или f-строки (работает начиная с Python 3.6). Вот в этом случае внутри строки в фигурных скобках указывается  имя переменной:

```
lbl.configure(text=f" Сумма = {x} .")
```